# address dependent locality field not shown

Tags: nodes, 8

drupal 8.8.2  address 8.x-1.7

address module is working in that i can add an address to my content, however I am not able to display the "dependent locality " field  even when it is set to "no override" or "required"

from the doc i did find : https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/customers/addresses/countries-and-subdivisions

it shows a "suburb" field, which i am assuming is this field.  I was planning to use this to contain the "county"

is there a dependency i need to check to enable this field ?

thanks for your time.

ps. i was not sure how to tag this question, i did not see a tag for modules or address

Answer (score 1):

i must be blind... right under the doc i was reading i see

The Commerce Guys addressing data set only includes subdivisions that are required for addressing.

so this field is not included because it is not needed for an address.

Answer (score 0):

Using Drupal 9 and address-8.x-1.10, this field can be enabled by adding it to the format.  Enable the field as either optional/required under field settings.  Then create an AddressFormatSubscriber with something like the following:

```
class AddressFormatSubscriber implements \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface
{

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[AddressEvents::ADDRESS_FORMAT][] = ['onAddressFormat'];
    return $events;
  }

  public function onAddressFormat(AddressFormatEvent $event) {
    $definition = $event->getDefinition();

    // Adds additional-name to format
    $format = $definition['format'];
    $format = str_replace('%additionalName', '', $format);
    $format = str_replace('%postalCode', "%postalCode %dependentLocality", $format);
    $definition['format'] = $format;

    $event->setDefinition($definition);
  }

}
```

(Don't forget to register in your-module.services.yml.)

As far as I can tell, this is required to display the field and to satisfy validation.

Here is the formal documentation on Address Formats:
https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/customers/addresses/address-formats